# Two way data binding in C3.js in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, c3.js, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to filter data in table with click on the bar chart (when I click on the bar, in the table appears corresponding record)

In the controller there is `onlick` method for getting the name from the object.

```
onclick: function(d, i) {
  $scope.country = d.name;
  console.log($scope.country);
}
```

There is also a table directive with isolated scope and it's expecting a country to be passed

```
.directive("countryItem", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "table.html",
      //isolated scope and 2-way bind country
      scope: {
        country: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.countries = [{"country":"Argentina","fifarank":7},{"country":"Belgium","fifarank":12}, {"country":"Croatia","fifarank":14}];
      }
    };
  });
```

so it's binded in directives isolate scope.

```
<tr ng-repeat="foot in countries | orderBy:orderByField:reverse | filter:search" country="country">
```

What I'm doing wrong? Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OhhaH5LIldTTagwZmnCk?p=preview), but onclick method works only on Firefox and older version of Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues here:

1) In your Plunker, you were not passing in a value for `country` to the directive - should be like this:

```
<country-item country="country"></country-item>
```

2) Syntax error on `filter` - should be like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="foot in countries | orderBy:orderByField:reverse | filter:country">
```

3) When you call Angular code from a D3 or other non-Angular event handler, you need to wrap it in a `$timeout` in order to trigger an Angular $digest cycle.

```
onclick: function(d, i) {
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.country = d.name;
    console.log($scope.country);
 });
}
```

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ETJSsJ2xB0ED54r0q2FS?p=preview)